# jquery return ajax success value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

if ajax is success, then i have to return that value and use it outside function like this :

```
let result;

function getGameNameFromWikiApi(searchParams) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://ko.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srprop=sectiontitle&srlimit=1",
        data: {
            srsearch: searchParams
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callbackData",
    }).done(function (result) {
        result = result.query.search[0].title
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}

console.log(result); // undefined

getGameNameFromWikiApi('something')
```

unfortunately, result return always undefined.

how can i get that success value?

Comment: did you call the  getGameNameFromWikiApi funtion?

Comment: yes i call it !

Comment: if you want to print it then you need to add async:false in ajax variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @MohanPrajapati `async: false` is very rarely an acceptable solution, and it absolutely is not one in this situation.